# Eclipse & Spigot - Trouble attaching source

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I've been trying to find a way to attach source into eclipse. I built the spigot.jarand decompiled it into a zip file using JD. [Here](https://www.mediafire.com/?qdc8trqdurvuf72) is the file if you want to take a look at the zip. Now what I'm having trouble doing is attaching the source to a project in eclipse. Yes, I of course have it in my build tools,

but I want to inspect some class' to see if I am using sockets/packets correctly. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5fqP.png) is the picture that eclipse gave me. I've already attached the source to that zip, but it wont work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to attach the jar as source, not a zip containing the jar

Comment: Maybe what you want is to attach the javadocs, not the source?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the built jar file the buildpath of your project. In eclipse just right-click your project, click on "Properties", select "Java Build Path", select the tab Libraries and click on the button "Add External Jar" on the right side. Then choose the Bukkit/Spigot jar file you want to work with and build against on export.

If you need a detailed video tutorial on it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dyopdta7ZI